# Tomcat setup for external access

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, tomcat

I have tomcat setup on a Windows 2008 server. Everything is running locally and works just fine. What I am trying to do is access the web app external now. I have opened a port so that incoming traffic will be sent to that server with tomcat on port 8780. When I ping the ip address of the server on an external network I get replies. When I telnet with the ip an port 8780 I connect. When I try to run a jsp with the ip and port number including the path to the jsp it just sits there and clocks.... IS there something I need to do to make tomcat accessible on the outside, something that i may have missed. Anything I can provide to help answer let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this: in my firewall port settings my admin had accidentally put an optional setting that takes the forwarded port and reroutes it to a newly defined port. Once he changed that life was good. So basically I had a port forwarding issue. (the firewall we use is actually untangle)